# User COUNT() in SQL Server query to be independent on the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to use COUNT function in SQL server to count number of orders per customer independent on the condition at the end.

```
    select u.FullName, u.Id, o.FullAddress, 
    Price, Payment, o.Created, StartDelivery as Delivering, 
    [Status], o.Id,

    (select COUNT(Orders.Id)
    from Orders 
    full outer join Users
    on Users.Id = Orders.CustomerId) as CountOfOrders

    from orders o
    full outer join users u
    on o.CustomerId = u.Id

    where [Status] = 0 and Payment = 1;
```

With this query I am getting what it appears to be total number of orders and its the number is in every row. i would like to group it by customer but not based on the condition at the end. I need total number of orders grouped by customer.

And with this query:

```
select u.FullName, u.Id, o.FullAddress, 
Price, Payment, o.Created, StartDelivery as Delivering, 
[Status], o.Id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerId) AS CountOfOrders

from orders o
full outer join users u
on o.CustomerId = u.Id

where [Status] = 2;
```

The count of orders is grouped, but according to the condition at the end. I need total number of orders grouped by customer regardless of that the condition at the end is. Apologies for repeating myself I just want to make sure I am clear :)

Thanks a lot for any input on this and for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select ou.*
from (select u.FullName, u.Id, o.FullAddress,
             Price, Payment, o.Created, StartDelivery as Delivering, 
             [Status], o.Id,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerId) AS CountOfOrders
      from orders o full outer join
           users u
           on o.CustomerId = u.Id
     ) ou
where [Status] = 2
```

By the way, you definitely do not need a `full outer join`.  If your tables are set up with proper foreign key relationships, then an `inner` join should suffice.  Do you really have orders where the `CustomerId` field is not a valid value in `users`?